# Jenkins API: Get a list of jobs filtered by build parameter - What jobs have built this Git commit?

Tags: api, jenkins

We are sending different parameters to our Jenkins jobs, among them are the Git commit SHA1. We want to get a list of jobs that used that parameter value (the Git SHA1 - which jobs ran this commit?).

The following URL will give us **all builds**:

```
http://jenkins.example.com/api/json?tree=jobs[name,builds[number,actions[parameters[name,value]]]]&pretty=true
```

It takes some time to render (6 seconds) and contains too many builds (5 MB of builds).

**Sample output from that URL:**

```
{
  "jobs" : [
    {
      "name" : "Job name - Build",
      "builds" : [
        {
          "actions" : [
            {
              "parameters" : [
                {
                  "name" : "GIT_COMMIT_PARAM",
                  "value" : "5447e2f43ea44eb4168d6b32e1a7487a3fdf237f"
                }
              ]
            },
(...)
```

**How can we use the Jenkins JSON API to list all jobs with a certain build parameter value?**

Comment: `/api/json?tree=jobs` do not traverse folders, if you have folders you need to run a rest call for each folder that shows up. just take the url returned for each folder and add `/api/json?tree=jobs`

Comment: Does this API have a documentation anywhere? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @zslim there is a bit documentation for the API right in Jenkins. take most Jenkins URLs and just add a `/api` (without the `/json` or `/xml`) to the end of it.

Answer (score 12):

Also been looking for this, and luckily i found an awesome gist

https://gist.github.com/justlaputa/5634984

To answer your question:

```
jenkins_url + /api/json?tree=jobs[name,color]
```

Using your example from above

```
http://jenkins.example.com/api/json?tree=jobs[name,color]
```

So it seems like all you need to do is remove the **builds** parameter from your original url, and you should be fine

Answer (score 9):

> How can we use the Jenkins JSON API to list all jobs with a certain build parameter value?

Not sure about JSON API, but you can use XML API and combine **tree** and **xpath** parameters:

```
http://jenkins_url/api/xml?tree=jobs[name,builds[actions[parameters[name,value]]]]&xpath=/hudson/job[build/action/parameter[name="GIT_COMMIT_PARAM"][value="5447e2f43ea44eb4168d6b32e1a7487a3fdf237f"]]/name&wrapper=job_names&pretty=true
```

Result sample:

```
<job_names>
  <name>JOB1</name>
  <name>JOB2</name>
  <name>JOB3</name>
  ...
</job_names>
```

**Note:** job falls into this list if at least one it's build was built with desired parameter

Answer (score 3):

It looks it isn't supported in JSON API, however if you can use XML API, it is possible to query via XPATH, see sample below

```
http://jenkins.example.com/api/xml?tree=jobs[name,builds[number,actions[parameters[name,value]]]]&exclude=hudson/job/build/action/parameter[value!=%275447e2f43ea44eb4168d6b32e1a7487a3fdf237f%27]
```

You may tune the better query string to fit for your needs.

credit to http://blog.dahanne.net/2014/04/02/using-jenkins-hudson-remote-api-to-check-jobs-status/

Answer (score 0):

Here's the query for passing jobs only:

`http://jenkinsURL/job/ProjectFolderName/api/xml?tree=jobs[name,color=blue]`

Here's the query for failing jobs only:

`http://jenkinsURL/job/ProjectFolderName/api/xml?tree=jobs[name,color=yellow]`